# How to add show/hide animations on ngIf in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In Angular 1, you could add a CSS class like **animate-show** to an element along with **ng-show**, but the same can't be done with Angular 2's **ngIf** since the element isn't rendered at all while hidden.

**CSS used in Angular 1 for animate-show:**

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove, .animate-hide.ng-
hide-add, .animate-hide.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-add-active,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove-active,
.animate-hide.ng-hide-add-active,
.animate-hide.ng-hide-remove-active {
  /* the transition is defined in the active class */
  transition: 1s linear all;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

In Angular 1, all you need is to add a CSS class "animate-show" to the element and it's good to go.

Is there an easy way to achieve this in Angular 2?

Comment: which attribute you have used in Angular 1.0 to apply the class name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass to apply the class name both conditionally and not in Angular

For Example

```
[ngClass]="'someClass'">
```

**Conditional**

```
[ngClass]="{'someClass': property1.isValid">
```

**Multiple Condition**

```
 [ngClass]="{'someClass': property1.isValid && property2.isValid}">
```

Also you can execute a method as an expression

```
[ngClass]="getSomeClass()"

 getSomeClass(){
        const isValid=this.property1 && this.property2;
        return {someClass1:isValid , someClass2:isValid};
    }
```

I hope this serve your need.